# How to disable ModemManager in linux mint?

Tags: linux-mint

When I setting up qmk_firmware, it throws

```
⚠ Detected ModemManager. Please disable it if you are using a Pro-Micro.
Ψ Problems detected, please fix these problems before proceeding.
```

I've tried both `systemctl disable ModemManager.service` and `sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service.disabled`, but neither works. Also tried to logout and in.

Didn't see any logs from this though.

```
$ systemctl list-dependencies multi-user.target | grep Modem
```

Comment: Maybe it's detecting the `modemmanager` package or the `/usr/sbin/ModemManager` program. Try removing modemmanager and see what happens.

Comment: I removed it using software manager but not working. Not sure how qmk detect it. Can't find any modem manager related in their repo.

Comment: You haven't read issue #7074, then.

Comment: Hi @JdeBP, thanks for pointing it out. Now I read it and it shows enabled somehow. `systemctl list-unit-files | grep ModemManager`. How do I disable it?

Comment: Ah, unmask the service made it work! `systemctl unmask ModemManager.service`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to disable `ModemManager` for an image I was building. As the service has an `alias` to `dbus` you need to `mask` the service to stop it starting:

- `systemctl mask ModemManager`